# How to get two variables from id of <a> and create ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Structure of my menu looks like below. In `id` of `<a>` I actually have two variables. The first one is located before _ and the second one is after _ (`first_second`). Every `<a>` is located in `<ul id="fotolia_menu">`

I would like to know how to get them from the id on click and create a click function that run ajax `thumb(first, second, 0);` with this variables.

JQUERY AJAX

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function thumb(paramType, param, page){
        $.ajax({
            url: "skrypt.php?paramType="+paramType+"&param="+param+"&page="+page
        }).done(function(data) {                            
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
    }
```

HTML

```
<ul id="fotolia_menu">
<li><a href="#">Kategorie</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3000000">Ludzie</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001000">W Studio</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001001">Mężczyzna</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001002">Kobieta</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001003">Niemowlę</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001004">Dziecko</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="cat1_3001005">Nastolatek</a></li>
```

// EDIT

Link's looks like this:

```
<ul id="fotolia_menu">
<li><a href="#">Kategorie</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3000000">Ludzie</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3001000">W Studio</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3001001">Mężczyzna</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3001002">Kobieta</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3001003">Niemowlę</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-paramType="cat1" data-param="3001004">Dziecko</a></li>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function thumb(paramType, param, page){
        $.ajax({
            url: "skrypt.php?paramType="+paramType+"&param="+param+"&page="+page
        }).done(function(data) {                            
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
    }

    $('#fotolia_menu a').click(function(){
        var paramtype = $elt.data("paramType");
        var param = $elt.data("param");
        thumb(paramType, param, 0);
    });
```

Comment: get the id of the anchor tag and use split function to the get the two values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you should probably not be including that information in the id attribute. What you should probably be doing is something like:

```
<a href="#" data-param1="cat1" data-param2="3001001">..</a>
```

Then you can use this code to get the values:

```
var param1 = $elt.data("param1");
var param2 = $elt.data("param2");
```

There is no reason to mess around with splitting the id tag, when HTML 5 provides such a great way to store meta information of an element with data attributes.

If you absolutely do not want to change the way you are doing things, then yes `split` is the right way to handle this as mopo922 has answered.

Comment: I've chosen your way. Now my links looks like this:

<a href="#" data-paramType="cat2" data-param="50010900">Inne</a>

but this:

$('#fotolia_menu a').click(function(){
var paramType = $elt.data("paramType");
var param = $elt.data("param");
thumb(paramType, param, 0);
});

won't work :(

Comment: @Axwell Could you put the new HTML and code in an edit to your original question. It is hard to look at all that in a comment. Also, I used `$elt` in my fiddle as that is what I named the JQuery object. Is that what yours is called?

Comment: @Axwell Use `$(this)` instead of `$elt`

Comment: @Axwell Yeah, you just copied the code from my fiddle blindly. `$elt` is not defined in your code. Put this line before the data calls: `var $elt = $(this);`

Comment: var param = $(this).data("param"); and still nothing.

Comment: I found the bug. All characters must be lowercase. I used var paramtype = $(this).data("paramtype"); insted of var paramtype = $elt.data("paramType");

Answer (score 2):

Add a click event that splits the `id` of the clicked element and passes those values as parameters to `thumb()`:

```
<script>
$('#fotolia_menu a').click(function(){
    var pieces = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    thumb(pieces[0], pieces[1], 0);
});
```

Alternatively, I really like the answer given by @thatidiotguy about using `data-` attributes instead.